# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for linked server (null)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ms-jet-ace

```
DECLARE @PATH NVARCHAR(1000) = N'\\MY-SERVER\C$\Folder\\'
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(50) = SUBSTRING(@FILENAME,0,CHARINDEX('.',@FILENAME))
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = 
    N'IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.' + @TABLE + ''' , ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.[' + @TABLE + ']
    SELECT * INTO [' + @TABLE + ']
    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0''
                    ,''Text; Database='+@PATH+';''
                    ,''SELECT * FROM [' + @FILENAME + ']'')'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Today I have come across an issue with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver in SSIS 2012. The script above sits in a stored procedure which dynamically loads the .csv's into the database based on the current file which is supplied by the SSIS loop in which stored procedure sits.  There are files in the directory.

The stored procedure runs correctly when run directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

This has been working fine up until today. Today I am getting the following error:

> Executing the query "EXEC [dbo].[CreateAndImportCSVs]  ?" failed with the following error: "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".". 
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Any help on this issue would be great!

**Edit**

So looking into what's changed I hear alarm bells when I look at the windows updates installed on the server yesterday! The following two were installed:

**Microsoft Office Access Runtime and Data Connectivity 2007 (SP3)**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526310

**Update for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB967642)**
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E93AB1BE-ADE6-4FF8-8637-DBD3EBE3C5C5&displaylang=en

Comment: So what changed today? Server fail over/move? Password change? Accounts change? Something changed, let's identify what and then we can work towards a resolution

Comment: @billinkc I've added some additional info to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem resolved itself. There were further updates installed, one of these must have fixed the issue introduced by the previous updates:

**Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB4011188) 64-Bit Edition**
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/4011188

**Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553347) 64-Bit Edition**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553347

**Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553338) 64-Bit Edition**
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553338

Thanks for all the help with this!

Answer (score 2):

Many things to Try:

1. Check the In Process and Dynamic Provider options for the ACE provider
2. Check the permissions on the Temp folder
3. Check the MemToLeave memory area allocated
4. Make sure the `EXCEL` process is not running in background
5. Made sure 'ad hoc distributed queries' was enabled (1)

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO

   EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO

   EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO

   EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
   GO

   EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
   GO
   ```

*Read more at [How to solve Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 error "Unspecified error"](https://visakhm.blogspot.ae/2013/12/how-to-solve-microsoftaceoledb120-error.html)*

Also i found an interesting suggested solution in the following link, take a look:

- [The OLE DB provider Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0 for linked server (null)](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-OLE-DB-provider-Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0-for-linked-server-null.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, 1 and 2 already done, and 3 not an issue as it runs successfully when run in SSMS.

Comment: CHeck the the `EXCEL` process is not running, even if the excel app is not opened

Comment: Read the last link

Comment: None of these solve the problem unfortunately, but like I said in the post when I run this directly from SSMS it runs correctly, the issue appears to be in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

The final piece that solved this for me was moving the spreadsheet to a windows directory that SQL Server was able to access.  I moved my spreadsheet to a new subdirectory, within the directly where my sql database was located, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not able to access the Access provider, if the installation of office was Click to Run installation.

The issue can be resolved by any of the following approaches.

[OLEDB driver issues resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb)

> ### Resolution
>
> Beginning with Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise Version 2009, work
> has been completed to break ACE out of the C2R virtualization bubble
> so that applications outside of Office are able to locate the ODBC,
> OLEDB and DAO interfaces provided by the Access Database Engine within
> the C2R installation.
>
> Use the following table to understand if additional components are
> necessary to access these intefaces within your environment:
> [image: OLEDB driver issues]

Answer (score 1):

Currently we installed 16.0. On one server both options N'AllowInProcess' and N'DynamicParameters' are set to 1 for the old 12.0 and the new 16.0 driver.

On the other server 12.0 worked well with both options set to 1. BUT 16.0 works only when they are both set to ZERO.

The IT swear both systems are the same.......

Comment: He wanted to say set AllowInProcess to 0 and set DynamicParameters to 1 to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a solution, but you should execute SQL with:

```
sp_executesql @SQL
```

It protects from injection and wotnot.

Comment: `sp_executesql` only protects against injection when you use a parameterized query and supply parameters for it.  Something like this: `EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorksPDW2012.dbo.DimEmployee WHERE EmployeeKey = @level',  N'@level tinyint',  @level = 109; `  There isn't any particular advantage here over `EXEC` since this dynamic SQL uses variables to represent names of objects, and you can't do that with a parameterized query.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see where @filename isn't declared.  I took that to mean it's an input parameter